# Что означает этот синтаксис? С++

Tags: c++, шаблоны-с++, синтаксис

В своих поисках наткнулся на вот такую функцию:

```
template<class T>
class Maybe : // ....

// ....

template <class M>
Maybe<M> fetch(M T::*mem_ptr) {
   return (bool(t)) ? Maybe<M>((*t).*mem_ptr) : Maybe<M>() ;
}
```

И не могу понять, что означает синтаксис `M T::*mem_ptr`? Как он называется и где можно про него почитать?

Comment: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/pointer

Comment: @ComeInRage, это *указатель на член*... по ссылке, в том числе, про это тоже есть...

Comment: @user7860670 достаточно было сказать, как человек выше, потому что по вашей ссылке довольно большой пласт информации

Comment: @ComeInRage ¿Видимо вы тоже не удосужились прочитать? ¿Или чтение первых трех предложений сейчас считает "большим пластом информации"?

Comment: Посмотрите еще на [invoke](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/invoke) и [монадичный optional](https://github.com/TartanLlama/optional). В сумме они позволяют использовать указатели на члены согласованным образом:  `findMyStruct().map(&MyStruct::name).map(&std::string::size).value_or(0)`.